# C++ detours linking issue

Tags: c++, header, linker-errors, static-linking

I have problems building my code that is using static lib detours. I am trying to do an old basic CTF. For that I want to get into detours.
Whenever I try to build my .dll file I get an issue

`LNK2019    unresolved external symbol _DetourTransactionBegin@0 referenced in function _DllMain@12`

Now, I have built the detours library using 3 different version of the visual studio dev console.
I have tried firing 'vcvars32.bat' and then using nmake to build the library which was able to build it, but I get the above error during linking my .dll. I have also tried building it with 'vcvarsamd64_x86.bat' and then using nmake to build it which also was able to build the library, but I still get the same error as above during linking.

I have tried the usual stuff: the include folder for detours.h is added to C++/General/Additional Include Directories.

Under Linker/Additional Library Directories I added them as follows: "C:\temp\det_retry\lib.X64";"C:\temp\det_retry\lib.X86";%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories).

And also under Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies I have the following: detours.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

What am I missing here? This is a blocker for me for a couple of days and I am reiterating the same steps trying to figure out what's missing but I cannot see. I'd really appreciate the input.

I am sure I am using the newest version because I have downloaded (cloned) detours from the ms github page.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your "Additional Library Directories" are setup incorrectly or contain invalid entries rather. They look like actual library file entries (i.e. pointing to some specific files) versus being only directories (e.g. "my/lib/path/for/my_project/"). Visual Studio's naming conventions are somewhat cryptic but they should be directory entries only. There should be an entry to whatever directory contains the detours.lib file (e.g. "MyProject/Libs/MSDetour" ... where MSDetour is a folder with the "detours.lib" in it) and then Visual Studio should find the library and link everything correctly.

As a side note, if you are using the Visual Studio developer console for building your project/solution you might want to look into CMake ... it is, in my opinion, significantly easier to work with (less "settings" digging) and maintain in the long-run.